# How do I make my PHP IDE understand Dependency Injection Containers?

Tags: php, ide, dependency-injection, phpstorm

Current situation: I have dependencies in my project that I solve by using dependency injection. I want to take the next logic step by using a dependency injection container (DIC) to ease the management of my dependencies and to lazy-load classes.

I looked at [Bucket](https://github.com/troelskn/bucket), [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), and [sfServiceContainer](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/), ran some test and really appreciate how DIC’s work. I’d probably go for Pimple because of its simplicity and raw power. If I didn’t have this problem:

Due to the abstraction that DIC’s offer, the IDE I’m using (PHPStorm) no longer understands what’s going on in my code. It doesn’t understand that $container['mailer'] or $sc->mailer is holding a class object. I also tried Netbeans IDE: same problem.

This is really a problem for me because my IDE becomes useless. I don’t want to program without code hints, autocompletion and refactoring tools when dealing with classes. And I don’t want my IDE to find all kinds of false positives when validating code.

So my question is: Has anyone dealt with this problem and found a solution?

Comment: you can try via phpdocumentor tags `/** @var $inst My_Object **/ $inst = $sc->mailer;`

Comment: You can vote on [WI-17116](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17116) if you are interested to have support for this in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can define class of the variable 'manually':

```
/** @var YourClassType $mailer */
$mailer = $container['mailer'];
```

In PhpStorm (and by [standards](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html)), use two asterisks and write the data type before the name of the variable.

You can write the data type without the name of the variable (but not the name without the data type).

Comment: The link you posted is about class variables.

Comment: @hakre: It applies to normal variables, too ;)

Comment: @nikic: How do you read this title: **@var - Document the data type of a class variable**? Would match the scope of PHPDoc fairly well, but whatever, no need to be pedantic.

Comment: @hakre, you are correct, and all the IDEs are doing it wrong.  I've wondered about that, too, but as you say:  pedantic.

Comment: netbeans does not support this example (thought it should) but does take types from phpdoc tags.

Comment: I think the trick is that you want to define this once in the container, not each time you use it - littering the code with phpdoc.

Comment: @thevikas You need to use a single asterisk with NetBeans and put the name before the type.

Comment: NetBeans example: /* @var $mailer YourClassType */

Answer (score 46):

While you can certainly tell your IDE the type of the object pulled out of your container *every time you access it,* it's better to do it once. Both of the following solutions involve subclassing the container. I just started using Pimple which recommends doing this anyway.

For containers that use instance members accessed with `->` or exposed via the magic `__get` method, you can tell your IDE what type they hold. This is great because it doesn't involve any additional parsing when the code is run--only the IDE is bothered by it.

```
/**
 * My container. It contains things. Duh.
 *
 * @property MyService $service
 * @property MyDao $dao
 */
class MyContainer extends Container { }
```

For Pimple and other containers that act as arrays you can create accessor functions for the top-level objects you'll need. While it means more parsing when the container is created, it should be done once and kept in APC. I vastly prefer a method over array access anyway since it places the easy-to-forget array key inside an auto-completed method.

```
class MyContainer extends Pimple
{
    /**
     * @return MyService
     */
    public function getMyService() {
        return $this['service'];
    }
}
```

BTW, for type-hinting inline variables with `@var` in NetBeans you need to use `/*` with **one asterisk**. This is *not* a doc-block comment and doesn't work with `/**` or `//`. Also, the name comes before the type.

```
public function foo() {
    /* @var $service MyService */
    $service = $container['service'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for the hint about single asterisk. the double asterisk was breaking it for me. thx.

Comment: The single asterisck syntax works on Eclipse PDT too, thank you!

Comment: In PhpStorm, the double asterisk works. /** @var MyService $service */.

Comment: And for the @property docblock.. This can be used in combination with magic __get(). But does it also work with array access? I doubt it. (At least in PhpStorm)

Comment: @donquixote No, `@property` is only for property access via `->`. For array access you'll need to created accessor functions until a new annotation is created for PHPDoc and implemented by IDEs.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Ok, that's what I thought. But the answer does not even mention magic __get(). Maybe it should be modified?

Comment: http://dqxtech.net/blog/2014-06-13/simple-do-it-yourself-php-service-container Not sure if Pimple also supports magic __get().

Comment: @donquixote The second paragraph directly addresses properties exposed via `__get`, but I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 14):

As the IDE's do not exectue the code, they do not know and need some help form you. I know this works for Eclipse and other IDEs as well: Hint the variable's type.

**Netbeans / Phpstorm / PDT / ZendStudio Example**

```
/* @var $mailer MailerInterface */
$mailer = $sc->mailer
```

Code complete starts to work again on `$mailer`.

For PDT it's important that:

1. The comment starts with one `*` only.
2. First the variable name, than the hint.

**Alternative Comment Variants**

As it was subject to a lot of discussion, it can differ between IDEs. However most IDEs support variable hinting for inline code variables in the way above. So depending on the IDE this might be written differently but similar, like here with two asterisks in front:

```
/** @var $mailer MailerInterface */
```

**PHPDoc compatibility**

PHPDoc parsers can have a problem if you mimic the class var doc-comment for inline code as so:

```
/** @var MailerInterface $mailer  */
```

That documentation is normally used for class variables ([@var - Document the data type of a class variable](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html)). PHPDoc is then missing the definition of the class variable after the comment which involves a burden for QA.

However some IDEs will offer code completition for simple variables as well when written in PHPDoc clas-variable style. I do not know if that has side-effects for the code-completition of the current class then as a new member might get introduced that actually does not exists.

Comment: please add another asterix in order to make it a valid phpdoc comment.

Comment: Second example shows wrong usage of phpdoc-comment. Type should be BEFORE variable only. It works just to support old code. http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html

Comment: @nikic: I dare to not do so as this is function body code not a phpdoc comment.

Comment: @hakre so PDT is a piece of crap. Because standard of phpdoc tells to write datatype first (see link in previous comment).

Comment: @OZ_: I beg your pardon, but it looks like that you have misread the phpdoc specs you linked which is about class variables. This is not a class variable but code in the function body. PDT naturally supports PHPDoc comments for class variables according to the specs you've linked.

Comment: @hakre: As OZ already said, PDT is indeed a piece of crap. The correct doccomment is `/** @var MailerInterface $mailer */`. Everything else might not be correctly recognized by better IDEs (most will have fallback code to support one asterix too, but you shouldn't rely on that.)

Comment: @hakre there is no differences between `class variables` and other variables. Also, this question tagged with `phpstorm` tag, not with `PDT` or `eclipse`. Here was my +1 for this answer, but you edited it to wrong variant.

Comment: @Blaise Kal, don't write type after name of variable.

Comment: @Blaise Kal: Can imagine so as it's part of the interface / class.

Comment: @Blaise Kal try to read comments - you'll find link to standards.

Comment: @hakre: This is in my file: `use namespace\MailerInterface;`, so it could know the namsespace already. But I’m not complaining :)

Comment: @hakre you wrote the link to the `fixed` issue :) one asterisk works in PhpStorm too (but just to support old code).

Comment: @Blaise Kal: Was not thinking so ;) And good to see it works for you. Can help a lot in such cases.

Comment: @OZ_: I'm still missing the correct link from you to the Phpdoc standard for standard variables. The one you've given is for class variables only, which has not been asked about here.

Answer (score 10):

For those who came here from google.

PHPStorm actually provides a way to solve this kind of problem instead of writing PHPDocs over and over again — creating and setting `.phpstorm.meta.php` file in a way [described here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) gains smoothly working autocomplete and type inspections.

Answer (score 1):

Pimple just introduce container builder principe. If you understand it, you don't need Pimple any more:

```
class Container
{
    private $shared = array();

    public function getService() {
        return new Service(
            this->getFirstDependence(),
            this->getSecondDependence()
        );
    }

    protected function getFirstDependence() {
        return new FirstDependence(
            this->getSecondDependence()
        );
    }

    protected function getSecondDependence() {
        return isset($this->shared[__METHOD__]) ? $this->shared[__METHOD__] : $this->shared[__METHOD__] =
        new SecondDependence(
        );
    }
}
```

This way Pimple does not hide type of object in mixed $c['some key']. You would have autocomplete suggestions when edit your container. Phpstorm is able to autoresolve method return type from your code. And you would have clear container.  You can ever override container:

```
class TestContainer extends Container
{
    protected function getFirstDependence() {
        return new FirstDependenceMock(
        );
    }
}
```

To be honest container written in 'programming' lanuage is wrong way to go. Container responsibility is to bring initialized graph of objects to caller. Having access to 'programming language' allows to violate that responsibility with easy. Some DSL for configuring dependency is better. Moreover most of original dependency information (argument typehints of constructors) is just ignored by Pimple and sfDepenencyContainer making your configuration bloated and fragile.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it's not object-oriented - it just uses classes... In your example, Container is not reusable, since you'll need to add/remove methods to it every time you have a new dependency. With Pimple, you just register new dependencies and never change the internals of the class like you do (classes should be closed to modifications).

Comment: Just to make sure people don't take this in consideration, I would strongly advise against this. Basically what I being done here is creating a serviceprovider with a pre-configured dependency chain. Not maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is about DIC only, but there is a [Silex Pimple Dumper](https://github.com/Sorien/silex-pimple-dumper) service provider which dumps the container to a json file. The same author wrote a [plugin for PHPStorm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7809) which can read that file and open the autocomplete with the service names and its type (class, string and etc). I'm using those two components and I can say that are good options for auto completion for Silex/Pimple.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I was looking for. This changes everything. :D