# annotating a local variable in php

Tags: php, variables, local, phpdoc

I am using Eclipse PDT and I want to annotate a local variable using Phpdoc.

All I see is that I can annotate the variables/properties of a class using `@var` or even 
`@property`, but how is this possible for a local variable?

How can I do something like this?

```
function foo(){
  /** @var Stock $a */
  $a->save();
}
```

Comment: Documentation/contracts generally only applies to exposed interfaces - e.g. fields and methods.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The Phpdoc standard does not cover these annotations (it only cover class properties with the `@var` tag); however, it is perfectly possible in Eclipse (e.g. PDT):

```
/* @var $variable Type */
 ^         ^        `--- type
 |      variable           
 |
 `--- single star
```

This also works in all other PHP IDEs like Netbeans or Phpstorm which is useful if you exchange your code with others.

Example Code:

```
<?php

/* @var $doc DOMDocument */
$doc->
```

Example Screenshot (Eclipse PDT (Indigo)):

[image: Eclipse PDT (Indigo)]

**Related Question & Answers:**

- [How do I make my PHP IDE understand Dependency Injection Containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395761/367456)
- [Is there a way to make PhpStorm's autocomplete “go deeper”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619709/367456)

Comment: I tried like this but it still fails: 
function foo(){
      /* @var $a Stock */
      $a->save();
    }

Comment: @tzortzik What do you mean with "it fails"? You know, that it is only for inspection?

Comment: @tzortzik: Which editor plugin are you using in Eclipse to edit PHP files? E.g. for me this perfectly works with code-completition in PDT (hammering CTRL + SPACE). Give Eclipse/DLTK some time to update, probably you need to place the comment in the line above the variable where you want to use it. At least that is how I normally do it. Not to the left of it but above. Like in your question.

Comment: @hakre: I did everything you said until my first post. I tried everything. I use the latest version of Eclipse PDT. I updated everything that is related to PHP and Eclipse.

Comment: @tzortzik: I can not explain why it does not work for you. I just create an example code and added a screenshot how it works for me in Eclipse Indigo PDT.

Comment: I find that if you obtain `$doc` from a function that has a `@return Type` annotation, this breaks the local `@var Type` inline annotation. Try commenting about the line that sets `$doc =` and you should get your hints.

Comment: Nice, it works for me.
Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: 3.2.0

Comment: @Pratsgogo: Thanks for your link, but if you read the answer I've already written that the phpdoc standard *does not cover* such variables.

Comment: If you want NetBeans to support alternative syntaxes as well, please comment/vote on the feature request: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=267470

Comment: **Note:** as said PHPDoc doesn't support this annotation over non-property variables, but as convention it's better to stick to its [DocBlock](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/docblocks.html) definition; hence the comment should start with double asterisk ```/**```.

Comment: I don't think there is any better. It's just undefined with an outcome of two variants and both have to be supported at that place.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but only for reference.
You must include the `Use` statement for the `Type` in current file in order to `@var` annotation work

```
<?php
use YourVendor\YourBundle\Entity\ProductType;

...

/* @var $product_type ProductType */
$foo = $product_type->getName();
```

Comment: `/* @var $product_type \YourVendor\YourBundle\Entity\ProductType */` works too

Comment: @marcel-djaman: Yes, of course. My answer points to the fact that it is necessary indicate the fully qualified name of the Type.