# PHP Docblock Type Hinting for Current Object in Magento Template?

Tags: php, magento, netbeans, docblocks

How might I hint at what `$this` is in the context of a Magento template, with a DocBlock?

As an example, `head.phtml` within the `template/page/html/` directory is an object of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`. The method I tried was:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
?>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem my IDE (*NetBeans*) is picking up on the hint. So my question is if there is a correct way of doing this so that NetBeans recognizes the hint.

Comment: Normally (but there was some discussion in the past), variable hints via comments are single-line only, normally with a single star at the beginning: `/* @var $this Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head */` - please try if this helps, I'm not sure about Netbeans. See as well: [How do I make my PHP IDE understand Dependency Injection Containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395737/how-do-i-make-my-php-ide-understand-dependency-injection-containers) **Edit:** However, I wonder why you need to typehint `$this`. Just curious, normally it should work as-is because of the file-context.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. Auto completion of `$this` hasn't worked for me in file-context from templates (although, if I'm extending a class or something similar.. it works)

Comment: Hmm, which Netbeans version are you using? I now have tested with 6.9 and `/* @var $this Bar */` works in a method of class `Foo` to give me the hints of type `Bar`. In Phpstorm 5.5 this works as well.

Comment: NetBeans 7.2 - could you post code? I'm curious if you declared `$this` after the DocBlock, which I'm not doing.

Comment: See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/pQpBu.png - And I normally do not use Netbeans, so my version is likely to be outdated. You probably should do a second, more recent Netbeans install in parallel and try with it, too.

Comment: I see - I'm not actually working within a class or method. It's a template file, or the view in the MVC. That's where the disconnect is. Netbeans version is current. Thanks for all your help, though - wish I could upvote you.

Comment: Update - The one-line, one-asterisk syntax actually worked: NetBeans had to scan for code changes for the change to take effect. Submit as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I just created *this* : http://i.imgur.com/Fzers.png :) - But why didn't you test when I first commented about exactly that ? ;)

Comment: NetBeans had to scan for changes in this case, which I would have assumed it would do automatically. Be sure to include that in your answer. In my case it only periodically scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans should accept it, at least my version 6.9 for

```
/* @var $this Bar */
```

does this:

[image]

and that is an example with the include scenario (no class around).

Take care to use the single-line - single-asterisk - type-of - commment.

Also take care Netbeans updated the index. As in your case:

> NetBeans had to scan for changes in this case, which I would have assumed it would do automatically. [...]. In my case it only periodically scans.

---

Docblock variable hinting related:

- [How do I make my PHP IDE understand Dependency Injection Containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395737/how-do-i-make-my-php-ide-understand-dependency-injection-containers)