# How can I create a PHPDoc for magic properties outside of the class definition?

Tags: php, slim, phpdoc

PHPDoc provides the [`@var` tag](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html), which should work even for variables declared outside of a class.

However, this does not seem to work if I define the variable as a magic member of an object:

```
/** @var $app->translator \Fortress\MessageTranslator */
$app->translator = new \Fortress\MessageTranslator();
```

Where `$app` is a [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com) object that supports arbitrary property assignment via magic setters and getters.

I know that I could add it to `Slim` itself via the `@property` tag, but then I would need to change the core `Slim` code every time I create a new property.

Does PHPDoc support this kind of dynamic property documenting?

Comment: Did you try removing `$app->translator` in the doc section? Anyway [this could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395737/how-do-i-make-my-php-ide-understand-dependency-injection-containers).

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Andy, I've started using Slim 3, which uses an explicit DI container.  So, something like what is shown in @onerror's answer _should_ work.  A similar answer is given in the link above.

Comment: @alexw Thanks, I was only trying to get type hinting working in my IDE for a dynamically assigned property. Ended up using a local variable and type hinting that with `@var` instad.

Comment: And this is just one example of why magic is bad.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need *$app->translator* in the doc block.
It should look like this:

```
/** @var \Fortress\MessageTranslator your_possible_comments */
```

or

```
/** @type \Fortress\MessageTranslator your_possible_comments */
```

[Link to the documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html).